# Matlab Gui interface

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to write a matlab gui code that will load data from CSV file and plot graph. And every time, I will load data by clicking the load data button, the plot should refresh and plot the new data. I was able to load data and plot first graph. However, If I click on the load data button second time and it loads data from different CSV file but it plots on the top of the first graph. I do not know how to refresh that graph every I load data and save it in a file new gui file .
Please help me out. This is the first time I am working with Gui interface. I am posting my Load data callback function below. and Gui interface  as .jpg attachment. Thank you.

```
    function shiva_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        hold off
    % load data
       %plot     
        yyaxis left
        loglog(t,a,'b')
        hold on
        loglog(t,t,'r')
        loglog(t,d,'c') 
        loglog(t,,'m')
        ylabel('% Text')
        xlabel('T')
        yyaxis right
        loglog(t,s,'y')
        loglog(t,st,'g')

        function ma_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% i tried uisave but not possible to run computer without matlab cause mcr
% does not run uisave
% i tried copyopbj but since i did not put a name on my figure it did not
% work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [`hold` set to `on`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) which means that all new plots placed on the `axes` will be *added* to the existing plots rather than replacing them. The easiest change that you can make is to call `hold off`  after you load the new data but before you start plotting (i.e. at the top of your callback).

```
function shiva_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % Ensure that our new plots overwrite existing plots
    yyaxis left
    hold off

    yyaxis right
    hold off

    handles.filename = uigetfile('*.xls');

    % Load data in

    % Now plot the new plots
    yyaxis left
    loglog(p, r, 'b');

    % Enable adding plots again
    hold on

    loglog(p, t, 'r');

    % Plot the rest of your stuff

    yyaxis right
    loglog(p, a, 'y')
    hold on
    loglog(p, h, 'g')
    ylabel('State and Status');
    grid on
```

Comment: @ParthaDey Did you try what I have posted? I'm assuming that you haven't

Comment: @ParthaDey You must have implemented it incorrectly. You should double check with my example.

Comment: @ParthaDey Geez, please don't paste that into a comment....edit your original post.

Comment: I have figured out. It is refreshing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ParthaDey What ended up solving it? If this answer helped please consider marking it as a solution

Comment: @ParthaDey Ok good to know. I've updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: I had another question. how do I save gui plot as fig. I have been trying it for while. it will save by clicking save button. which I have built.

Comment: @ParthaDey You want to use [`savefig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html)

Comment: I am modifying my code to give to you save call back function here.  I do not know the save of my fig

Comment: @ParthaDey I'm not sure what you're asking. It is probably better-suited to a different question.